# MySQL/PHP - Avoid duplicates - (INSERT, UNIQUE, REPLACE)

Tags: php, mysql, replace, unique, profile

I've been working on my own/small social-media platform and I'm almost done except for the following problem:

I have profiles for all my users where one user is able to comment on somebody elses profile. So there is a user table that looks like:

id | name | first_name | ... |

And a table to add/retrieve the comments to/from:

id | author_id | receiver_id | comment |

All of that is working great except for one little problem: I want to make sure that every user can only comment once on any profile. After that they would overwrite their previous comment. That means I have to check for the same "author_id" AND "receiver_id" combination before inserting a comment into the database.

Researching this I found out that there are "unique"-keys in which you can combine the two columns but I'm not exactly sure about either how to implement it for my current problem or even if it's the best way to go.

Example (user):

1, Doe, John

2, Doe, Jane

Example (comment):

1, 1, 2, "Hi, I'm great!" (John comments on Jane)

2, 2, 1, "What's up?" (Jane comments on John)

Example (Insert):

XXX, 1, 2, "Nevermind" (John comments again/changes his comments and #1 is replaced)

New result (Comments):

1, 1, 2, "Nevermind" (New comment by John)

2, 2, 1, "What's up?" (Janes comment stays the same)

If you could help me out here - that'd be great!

Best regards, Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a UNIQUE key and REPLACE statements to do this.

An example of such a table would be:

```
CREATE TABLE profile_comment (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    author_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    receiver_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    comment TEXT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY id,

    UNIQUE (author_id,receiver_id)

) [...character set and collation...];
```

You'd then use a statement like this to insert or update the table:

```
REPLACE INTO profile_comment(author_id,receiver_id,comment)
VALUES (<n>,<n>,<text>);
```

Source: [MySQL 5.0 Manual, REPLACE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Note that you would have to **avoid** giving an id parameter to the REPLACE statement, as both the primary key and the unique key can each cause a record to be deleted in that scenario.

Comment: The best solution in my opinion. Marginal note: You can try to make some php mess up code to avoid duplicate comments, but it should be of course optimised in the database layer. In that case Your database is stable, and in the future possible other applciations that are connecting to Your database will not mess anything up. Good practice is also to use ON DUPLICATE KEY to autoclean / autoupdate database tables if this is needed. Maybe this note will help someone. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

At first you add the unique key:

```
 ALTER TABLE comment ADD UNIQUE( author_id, receiver_id);
```

Than you can insert or update with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO comment (author_id,receiver_id ,comment ) VALUES (1,2,"Nevermind") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE comment = VALUES(comment)
```

For more information you can look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html